# convert string to array number

Tags: matlab

how to convert a string to an array of numbers? in example : 
`str='1,2,3,4.5' to number=[1 2 3 4.5]`.

I wrote the code below, but it has a problem.

```
str='1,2,3,4.5';
tmp = regexp (str,',','split');
tmp2=[];
for(i=1:length(tmp))
tmp2(i)=cell2mat(tmp(i))
end
```

Comment: Future readers should check the answers to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895220/reading-character-by-character-from-a-string-into-an-array for very concise methods of converting strings to array of numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, @ame.b's answer is the correct one. But for the sake of diversity, you can also do the following in this case, because the separators are `,`:

```
str2num(str)
```

Comment: Even better, I say! I just did not think of this one as I rarely use it myself.

Comment: `str2double` is safer, especially since `str2num` is based on `eval`. I wouldn't recommend using `str2num`.

Answer (score 3):

`str2double` is what you need where you used `cell2mat`.

**edit:** You can even replace the final four lines (i.e. the `for` loop and the initialisation of `tmp2`) by a call to `cellfun`:

```
tmp2=cellfun(@str2double,tmp)
```

Comment: @ame.b: You don't need cellfun to run str2double on cell array of strings. Just `str2double(tmp)` should work.

Answer (score 3):

I must be missing something here, but why can't you just use `sscanf`?
For example:

```
sscanf('1,2,3,4.5','%f,')

ans =

 1.0000
 2.0000
 3.0000
 4.5000
```