# Reading character by character from a string into an array

Tags: matlab

What is the usual way in MATLAB *to read* an integer into an array, digit by digit?

I'm trying to *split* a four digit integer, `1234` into an array `[1 2 3 4]`.

Comment: Is `1234` a numeric value (like the body of the question suggests) or a string (`char`, like the title suggests)?

Comment: @tmpearce - It can actually be either, but for now I am more interested in the case where it is a numeric value. Sorry about the title confusion.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very easy way to do it for a single integer

```
s = num2str(1234)
for t=length(s):-1:1
   result(t) = str2num(s(t));
end
```

The most compact way however, would be:

```
'1234'-'0'
```

Comment: @Dan This uses the fact that character codes are ordered in the same way as numbers. So the character code of `'1'` is exactly 1 higher than the character code of `'0'`.  Try `'0' + 0` to find out what the codes actually are.

Comment: right I see, excellent solution. Why even bother to post the loop?

Comment: @Dan As the loop can be generalized more easily. With this method it is not so hard to produce `[12 23 34 41]` for example.

Comment: Note: for a matrix of numbers,   `num2str(matrix) - '0'` will sorta work, but will return a bunch of columns of `-16` due to the spaces in the character matrix produced with `num2str`

Answer (score 4):

Or try this

```
result = str2num(num2str(1234)')'
```

Comment: This works, but sadly not for a matrix of values (as opposed to the vector in your example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html)

```
arrayfun(@str2num, num2str(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elegant and efficient solution using a recursive function:

```
function d = int2dig(n)
   if n >= 10   
      d =  [int2dig(floor(n/10)),mod(n,10)];
   else
      d = n;
   end
```